# React-Native code-push compatibility issue

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I am using Code-Push for my react-native project. I did such configuration quite-well. But after build it is successful I am seeing error in react-native CLI like below. I was thinking that this issue is about compatibility. I tried several ways. I read documentation bu

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTwtM.jpg)

Comment: try upgrading the react library, like `npm i react@16.0.0-alpha.12`

Comment: It had already."dependencies": {
  "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
  "react-native": "0.43.0",
  "react-native-action-button": "^2.7.1",
  "react-native-code-push": "^2.0.1-beta",
  "react-native-dismissable-numeric-keyboard": "0.0.2",
  "react-native-material-ui": "^1.12.0",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
  "react-native-video": "^1.0.0",
  "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
  "update": "^0.7.4"
 },